# What is $\lim_{x\to(\pi/2)}(1+\cos x)^{\tan x}$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions

> What is $$\lim_{x\to(\pi/2)}(1+\cos x)^{\tan x}$$

This question came up in a book on Real Analysis. I applied L Hopital's rule, but was unable to reach the answer.

$$\lim_{x\to(\pi/2)}(1+\cos x)^{\tan x}=L$$
$$\ln L=\lim_{x\to(\pi/2)}\tan x\ln (1+\cos x) $$
Writing it as $\dfrac{\ln (1+\cos x)}{\dfrac{1}{\tan x}}$, we get 0/0 form. Applying L Hopital's, it keeps getting longer. What is the right way of solving this?

> The answer was given as $e$

Comment: Let $u=\tan{x}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without L'Hospital:

$$\ln L=\lim_{x\to(\pi/2)}\tan x\ln (1+\cos x)= \lim_{x\to(\pi/2)}\frac{\ln (1+\cos x)}{\cos x}\cdot\tan x\cos x = $$$$=\lim_{x\to(\pi/2)}\frac{\ln (1+\cos x)}{\cos x}\cdot\sin x = 1\cdot0 = 0$$

I used the known limit:$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln (1+x)}{x}=1$$

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't get longer:
$$\frac{[\log(1+\cos x)]'}{\left[\dfrac{1}{\tan x}\right]'}=\frac{\sin^3x}{1+\cos x}.$$

Answer (score 1):

(Without L'hopital) Considering that $\sin \frac{\pi}{2}$ is an actual value in this situation, you can see the correlation between,

$$\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}}{\big(1 + \cos x\big)^{\frac{1}{\cos x}}}$$

and

$$\lim_{n \to 0}{\big(1 + n \big)^{\frac{1}{n}}}$$